# Firefox built in dev Inspector tool, browser bug with hidden input in HTML

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I use Normal Firefox with Dev Tool.

The Explanation: I use hidden input fields to store some data. So I have noticed twice, that the browser is mixing all input fields completely up, it does not understand what is what at all.

Simplified example HTML on server:

```
<input id="test" type="hidden" value="Hello there"><input id="something" type="hidden" value="0">
```

Firefox gets above HTML from server (clear cache, reload the page, nothing fixes this):

```
<input id="test" type="hidden" value="0"><input id="something" type="hidden" value="Hello there">
```

(and now thinks that id 1 is id 2 etc)

Once I Restart my browser, all gets normal again. (Like example shows, there is no human error, just nonsense) Anyone else had this, if not, then look out before hurting yourself. I don't know if normal users may actually experience this but they may. Someone can explain this...

Comment: Does this also happen on a fresh Firefox profile? Or on any other website? I can't find anything like that in the [Firefox bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). So I assume it is either an add-on you have that is causing this or some code on your site.

Comment: It does not happen just like that, it's really rare, once I get it exhausted like clearing 100 times cache and use dev tools for long period at once, even then it may or may not happen, once it messes up the HTML, the HTML is no longer updated from the server even after clearing the cache(refresh should restart all JS intervention if present, there is none).  Just a restart will fix all. I am working with one site. Add-on: a spellcheck/dictionaries  (2 languages actually), video codec, widevine content decryption module by google inc (def plugins) that's all.

Comment: If you can exclude that it's related to your website, it is either a browser bug or some issue related to your add-ons. Though it's impossible to say without being able to reproduce the problem. If you can somehow break it down to a simple, reproducable test case, you should [report it to Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi).

Comment: Once I experience it again I try to do more digging, if the soil is soft, but I doubt that.

Comment: I don't think that's related to Firefox (or browser in general). can you log the generated HTML in server side (before sending it to client) (of course if it's not generated in client using JS)? which technology do you use? (nodejs, asp.net, ...)